# Start JavaFlightRecorder from attached agent or by using com.sun.tools.attach.*;

Tags: java, jvm, javaagents

Is it possible to build custom agent (or reuse existing one) that would enable JFR features in HotSpot VM?.

My plan is to build simple agent loader that uses `com.sun.tools.attach.*` package to attach to VM and load custom agent.

I don't use jcmd or other JDK tools intentionally as I don't have control over environment, because applications run in containers where I don't have control about JRE/JDK and ABI for jcmd (so I cannot copy parts of JDK there just to run commands).

I know that agents can do almost anything and since jcmd is written in java and it is capable of starting FlightRecording on fly (I presume via some JMX) then it should be possible also via java agent, but I cannot find documentation for that.

Any lead would help. Thanks

Comment: You can use [jattach](https://github.com/apangin/jattach) - a tiny self-contained non-Java utility that can be used in place of jcmd to start flight recording etc.

Comment: That's complicated solution as I would have to detect architecture and match ABI (mentioned above). Optimal would be Java based solution as Java class and bytecode is transferable between architectures and independent on shared libraries, etc. Is there any?

Comment: @apangin But your comment has lead me to potential solution - it's attach API https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/jdk/api/attach/spec/index.html which should work from Java as well.
Thanks for pointing jattach to me as well. Can you please provide it as an answer so you can get credit for that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dynamic Attach API (com.sun.tools.attach) will not work with JRE 8, since it requires `tools.jar` and `libattach.so` which are included in JDK, but not in JRE.

[jattach](https://github.com/apangin/jattach) is a small standalone utility written in C; it provides dynamic attach functionality for JRE and can be used in place of jcmd:

```
jattach <pid> jcmd "JFR.start ..."
```

If you prefer Java API, you may use [ByteBuddyAgent](https://javadoc.io/doc/net.bytebuddy/byte-buddy-agent/latest/index.html). It also provides dynamic attach capability without dependency on com.sun.tools.attach.

```
try (VirtualMachine.ForHotSpot.Connection conn =
             VirtualMachine.ForHotSpot.Connection.ForJnaPosixSocket.Factory
                     .withDefaultTemporaryFolder(30, 100, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS)
                     .connect(pid)) {
    conn.execute("1", "jcmd", "JFR.start", null, null);
}
```

Comment: thanks, i was missing the double quotes surrounding JFR.start together with its arguments, which was causing "argument is mandatory" error.